# jquery easeOutBounce horizontal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-easing

I'm trying to do a easeOutBounce horizontal animation, but all i succeed to do is vertical easeOutBounce, with this : `$('#tester').slideToggle(1000,'easeOutBounce');`

here is my jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/newzy08/xpvt214o/372035/

I haven't seen any easeOutBounce effect with jquery slide() function...

What may i change in my code for switching from vertical to horizontal easeOutBounce ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this with a bit of change in your css

```
$('#tester').animate({
  width: '300px'
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  specialEasing: {
    width: "easeOutBounce"
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hnpt4xgb/